# How do I find a specific string in a single column of a sheet?

Tags: node.js, iterator, smartsheet-api

I have a sheet, with an ID. That sheet has a column, with a text field, like below.

```
            Column
```

---

```
 1         551_file     
 2         552_file    
 3         553_file    
 4         554_file
```

How can I iterate through all the strings in the column, to find, say "552_file"?

So far, I've looked at the [smartsheet API docs](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/columns#operation/column-get), mostly the Get Column.
However this returns the column as an object. I'm looking for a way to iterate through the data of the column, not interested in the column itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this even a node question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 'get sheet' method: https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/sheets#operation/getSheet

It will return a JSON object that includes rows.